# I write a program but it misses something and I don't know how to take the rent from loop

Tags: java

A real estate office handles 50 apartment units. When the rent is $600 per
month, all the units are occupied. However, for each $40 increase in rent,
one unit becomes vacant. Each occupied unit requires an average of $27 per
month for maintenance. How many units should be rented to maximize the
profit?

Write a program that prompts the user to enter:

- The number of apartment Units
- The rent to occupy all the Units
- The increase in rent that results in a vacant unit
- Amount to maintain a rented unit

The program then outputs the number of units to be rented to maximize
the profit

---

**but I want to show to the user the rent and I don't know how**

```
import java.util.*;
public class yeungah {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        double rent, maintenance, maintenanceCost, increase;
        double result=0, profit, maxProfit = 0;
        int h=0, number;

        System.out.println(" enter the number of apartment units: ");
        number=input.nextInt();

        System.out.println( " enter the rent value for all the occupied units: ");
        rent=input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The increase in rent that results in a vacant unit: ");
        increase=input.nextInt() ;

        System.out.println( "enter the  maintain value for each occupied unit: ") ;
        maintenanceCost=input.nextInt() ;

        for (int i = number; i > 0; i--, rent += increase)
        {
            result = i * rent ;
            maintenance = i * maintenanceCost ;
            profit = result – maintenance ;

            if (profit > maxProfit)
            {
                maxProfit = profit ;
                h =i ;
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "Number of units to be rented in order to maximize profit is: "+maxProfit) ;
        System.out.println("It occurs when Number of occupied Units is:"+h) ;
    }
}
```

**can anyone help?**

Comment: its unclear what rent you want to show to the user individual or commulative?

Comment: [How to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Just as a point never trust user inputs. Always check them after getting them.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan I want rent when the profit is max

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I cant make comments yet but I'm curious.
When does the for loop end? I cant see that it ever reached i>0 since i is always decreasing and I cant see that i is changed in the for loop.

I would use a while loop that breaks when profit isn't larger then maxprofit.

In the end it should be enough to take number-h to answer the assignment question

Take everything I write with a grain of salt since I'm also a rookie. :)

Comment: This would be better as a comment on the question rather than an answer!

Comment: Hi, yeah thats why I wrote "Sadly I cant make comments yet but I'm curious" I cant make comments yet but I was interested in the assignment

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that. Keep up and soon enough you'll be making comments. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To show the rent after each increase do System.out.println(rent) at the end of the for loop.
To show the rent at the end you would do the same thin after the loop.

A problem I'm seeing here is that you don't seem drop out of the loop once the max profit is found. I would recommend a boolean flag. Set it to false have it as a condition along with 1 > 0.
Then within the loop add an else to your if statement setting it to true.

This will cause the loop to drop out once the max profit is found.

Comment: thanks . i dont understand what are mean about the problem

Comment: For example If you find the maxProfit when 40 rooms are occupied it doesn't stop.

In the example you have above it's not a big issue but if you have a larger project doing more complex processes this could cause a large slowdown in the speed of your application.

It's good to get into the practice of exiting processes when whatever is being done is completed rather than wasting memory.